# Searching for a tuple in another list of tuples is not working with "in" condition

Tags: python-3.6

Can't figure out why my "not in" condition is not working. I have two Lists (all_cameras and some_cameras). One contains "Row" type elements (fetched from a database with: all_cameras = cursor.fetchall()), the other contains "tuple" type elements.

Currently, the lists are identical, so the first items should match perfectly to each other; however, when I do a test to see if the item from "some_cameras" is anywhere in the list of "all_cameras", it always says it wasn't found. Am I not able to use "in/not in" conditioning for this type of thing?

```
for v_c in some_cameras:
   logging.info("Checking if this item is in the all_cameras tuple:")
   logging.info(v_c)
   logging.info("{} is the first element in the all_cameras list".format(all_cameras[0]))
   if v_c not in all_cameras:
        logging.info("{} was not found in the all_cameras tuple".format(v_c))
```

Log output:

```
[2020-01-16 12:40:53,588] INFO - MainThread - root - Checking if this item is in the all_cameras tuple:
[2020-01-16 12:40:53,591] INFO - MainThread - root - ('computer', 'cam', '192.168.0.1', 1, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-accc8e741751')
[2020-01-16 12:40:53,603] INFO - MainThread - root - ('computer', 'cam', '192.168.0.1', 1, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-accc8e741751') is the first element in the all_cameras list
[2020-01-16 12:40:53,605] INFO - MainThread - root - ('computer', 'cam', '192.168.0.1', 1, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-accc8e741751') was not found in the all_cameras tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can't do what I was trying to do because it was a "Row" and a "tuple" being compared. I updated my code to make each a list of lists, and now it works as expected. The code I used to convert the SQL output was:

```
all_cameras = cursor.fetchall()  # list of Rows
all_cameras = [list(item) for item in all_cameras]  # list of Lists
```